# Segmentation Fault caused by a read into the client

Tags: c, sockets, segmentation-fault

I wrote this code for a simple client/server application:

This is a portion of the code of the server:

```
while(TRUE){
    struct sockaddr_in clientName = {0};
    int simpleChildSocket = 0;
    unsigned int clientNameLength = sizeof(clientName);

    simpleChildSocket = accept(simpleSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&clientName, &clientNameLength);
    if (simpleChildSocket == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot accept connections!\n");
        close(simpleSocket);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* write out our message to the client */
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "OK %s", MESSAGE);
    write(simpleChildSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer));

    /* Start server operations */
    array = NULL, j = 0, k = 0, numberSample = 0;
    tmpValue = NULL;
    do{ 
        do{

            memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
            returnStatus = read(simpleChildSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            if(returnStatus <= 0)
                fprintf(stderr, "Status: %d\n", returnStatus);

            for(i = 0; i < (int)strlen(buffer); i++){
                if(isdigit(buffer[i]))
                    flag = 1;
                else if(isspace(buffer[i]))
                    continue;
                else{
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(flag == 0){
                memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
                snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), BOLD RED "ER" RESET " Devi inserire solo numeri\n");
                write(simpleChildSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer));
            }
        }while(flag != 1);

        token = strtok(buffer, " ");
        digit = atoi(token);

        if(digit != 0){
            printf("Token #%d: %d\n", k, digit);
            k++;
        }
        else
            printf("Ricevuto %d\n", digit);

        numberSample += digit;

        array = realloc(array, numberSample * sizeof(int));

        for(i = 0; (tmpValue = strtok(NULL, " "))!= NULL; i++, j++){
            array[j] = atoi(tmpValue);
        }

    }while(digit != 0);

    for(i = 0; i < numberSample; i++)
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, array[i]);

    printf("\n\n<%d>\n\n", numberSample);

    free(array);
    close(simpleChildSocket);
}
```

Instead this is a portion of the code of the client:

```
/* get the message from the server */
memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
returnStatus = read(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
if(returnStatus > 0)
    printf("%s", buffer);
else
    fprintf(stderr, "Return Status: %d\n", returnStatus);

/* start client operations */
do{
    memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    /*fflush(stdout);*/
    write(simpleSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer));

    memset(string, '\0', sizeof(string));
    returnStatus = read(simpleSocket, string, sizeof(string));
    if(returnStatus > 0)
        printf("%s\n", string);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Return Status: %d\n", returnStatus); 

}while(atoi(&buffer[0]) != 0);
```

The problem is that when I send data for the first time to the server, the latter goes into segmentation fault. The problem is caused by the client's read, which must take the error if the user attempts to send letters or symbols instead of the numbers. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: If you use a debugger to catch the crash as it happens, where in *your* code does it happens? And please take some time to read about [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "OK %s", MESSAGE);` you should add a '\n' here. (and strlen() doen **not** include the NUL teminator, so the receiver won't be able to find the eind of the "message" ) BTW: snprintf() returns the length of the resulting string, so you dont even need the strlen(). BTW2 `memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));` is a bad habit. Instead use the retun values from read() and write() to find out the length of the recieved chunks.

Comment: 'printf("%s", buffer);' is UB if the whole buffer is filled by the read.

Comment: 'while(atoi(&buffer[0]) != 0);' if one char only is read, the loop could return without the result you desire.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit  The problem is not the `atoi` because even if you check that value to a variable and then use it as a loop condition does not work. I found out that the problem is the read because if i comment the code, the client works